# Handle wrong file input name. Program crashes when reading in i file from argv with the wrong name. C programming

Tags: c, file

Im trying to figure out how to handle the exception of a user typing in the wrong filename. Im running the program via the terminal. If I try to run the program without a file the program prints the error message as supposed to. But if I run the program and type in the wrong filename it crashes. Any suggestions on how i should handle this? Thank you!

**Code**

```
FILE *file;

file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (argv[1] == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: No file input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Don't edit the title, accept an answer instead if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[1] == NULL` just tests that `argv[1]` exists/is not `NULL`, not that it contains the name of a valid, readable file. Fortunately, the `fopen` call does check for that. If `file == NULL` after calling `fopen`, then `fopen` failed for any reason; one possible reason is that the file doesn't exist.

Also, to test for the presence or absence of a command-line argument in `argv`, you can just use the value of `argc`:

```
if(argc < 2) // No filename supplied
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: myprog filename\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if(file == NULL) // Filename supplied but fopen failed
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open \'%s\'", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: While the advice to check for `file == NULL` is correct, your answer (with its `if`/`else` construct) seems to suggest checking `argc < 2` after calling `file = fopen(argv[1], "r")`, which may lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ace You're right; thanks for pointing that out. Updating my post now...

Comment: @OscarThorwid if you found my answer to have solved your problem, then you could mark it as accepted.

Comment: just figured out how to do that hehe! sorry! :)

Comment: Consider using `perror()` to give more indication as to *why* the file couldn't be read.

Comment: @TobySpeight `perror` only works if `errno` is set. A lot of C implementations will have `errno` set after an `fopen` call, but it’s not required by the C standard.

Comment: Thanks - I assumed that it was a C requirement, but it turns out that non-POSIX systems could leave it unset.  I never needed to know that, but I do now!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the if Statement before opening the file

```
FILE *file;

if (argv[1] == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: No file input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} 
file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

Comment: Still getting "segmentation fault: 11"

Answer (score 0):

handle with the return of the fopen function
if it is null then print file not exists or wrong file name given by user
else will open the file

whenever u open file in read mode, it checks whether file exists or not
if not exist then return null

now to give better info to user as he missed to enter file name or entered wrong file name

first check command line file input, if that is null print message as file name not entered

after that check what your fopen function is returning, if returning null print invalid file name

```
if(argv[1]==Null)
    printf("File Name not entered")
else
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fp==Null)
        print("wrong file name given");
    else
        do all your operations
```